# Render non geographical map tile with React Native (React-native-maps)

Tags: three.js, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-native-maps

I need to render my custom map tiles based on my own cartesian coordinates (not based on geospatial coordinates). I provide those tiles from my own backend.  I found the library react-native-maps great since it integrates with react native directly without any webview. Can I define CRS (coordinate reference system) with that libary to fit my case or do you recommend any other libraries ?

I tried to render point cloud png based map tiles on my react native app.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible with react-native-maps.  See discussion here: https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/1460